# Browser automatic creation of html tag when the text of asp:LinkButton starts with '<'

Tags: c#, html, tags, html-rendering

I create a new web project in Visual studio and put one asp:LinkButton Control in Default.aspx.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat ="server" ID="lnkTest"><lll</asp:LinkButton>
```

When I start the project and Visual Studio redirects me to the browser nothing is render. If I go to View Page source everything looks fine

```
<a id="MainContent_lnkTest" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$lnkTest&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><lll</a>
```

If i go to Inspect Element, the tool show me this:

```
<a id="MainContent_lnkTest" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lnkTest','')"><lll< a>

    </lll<></a>
```

Why this happen and can I fix it.

P.S. If the text not start with '<' rendering is normal and the control is visible.

Comment: It's happening because it's treating it as a start of a tag, you need to use the `html entity` of `<`, which is `&lt;`

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<` if you want it to appear as normal text. Use an [html entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) instead:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat ="server" ID="lnkTest">&lt;lll</asp:LinkButton>
```

Use `&lt;`, `&#60;`, or `&#x3C;`, any one should work.

Comment: @MartinStanchev Questions are generally closed only if they are duplicates of other questions, off topic, unclear, too broad, or primarily opinion based. This question doesn't seem to meet any of those conditions so it should remain open IMO, although you may still delete it if you want. If the answer resolved your issue, you should consider accepting it. This helps other users who might run into a similar issue know that the answer may be of use to them as well.